# Combining non-adjacent rasters using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst

I am trying to combine two rasters and would like to get rid of the blank site.

How can I do that using ArcMap?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you combine these in a mosaic dataset you can then edit the footprint of the image to remove the whites space. This will not edit the image itself but just the visualisation of it.

Another option, if the whitespace is no data, would be to set no data as transparent in the display properties of the image.

Comment: Thanks. When I combine these two rasters, the gap gets "0" value and I could not find a way to combine it. I used focalstatistics and raster calculator as well but it did not work.